# Make a class that has an array of classes

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an object with an array:

```
extension Schedule {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Schedule> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Schedule>(entityName: "Schedule")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var days: [Day]? 
}
```

and days variable is an array of class Day:

```
public class Day : NSObject{
    var dayTitle:String
    
    init(dayTitle:String){
        self.dayTitle = dayTitle
    }
}
```

currently I only have one string.
when I run this it says

error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x600003719b00> , The data couldn’t be written because it isn’t in the correct format.

I think I need to do something with NSCoding but I'm not sure how

I tried something like this

```
import Foundation

public class Day : NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding{
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
    

    var dayTitle:String
    
    init(dayTitle:String){
        self.dayTitle = dayTitle
    }
    
    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(dayTitle,forKey: "dayTitle")
    }
    
    public required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let dayTitle = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dayTitle") as! String
        self.init(dayTitle: dayTitle)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You should make Day an entity (NSManagedObject subclass) as well and create a one-to-many relationship between Schedule and Day, that is probably the easiest way forward

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if I do this can I have them in a certain order and be able to reorder them however i like?

Comment: You can sort them when fetching (NSSortDescriptor) or afterwards, if you need to sort them in the order created you need to add a timestamp or some sorting key.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks!